# what OS build is needed on the XBox Dev Mode so we can see that we have Creators Program Dev kit instead of UWP app kit?

Tags: xbox, xbox-one, dev-mode

I joined the Creators Program Preview while my XBox One was still in beta preview (so had the march update already), and then when I used Dev Mode it was showing up that I was in the creators program when you look in the Dev Home page. But since it was required to be out of any preview program before getting into any Dev Mode I had to opt out of the other program. Since then my XBox One updated to the public retail version of its OS (anniversary update) and the dev mode has been changed to that as well, and now I only see UWP app kit. Is it possible that dev mode will update to a preview build so I can use it with the Creators Program?

Comment: xbox one is activated in my dashboard on devcenter

Answer (score 0):

Dev mode works for any UWP, whether it is a game or application. The Xbox Live Creators Program will allow you to eventually publish the game into the Store for the Xbox One. tl;dr, you are good to go :)

Note that I've been using the Creator's preview builds, which have more performance available for UWP processes, for some time now. We aren't officially supporting it since the Xbox Live Creators Program is also in preview - but it should work for you.

Note that you can use the xbox-live tag in future for any Xbox Live Creators Program questions.